# How can I create a login database in asp

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, authentication

I have created a login page and I have used Login Control and here's my code

[image]

but ASP.NET does not make login database automatically... and I see a big error :

[image]

What do you suggest to solve this problem ?

If there is no way so :
How can I use Class ***Roles*** to add a role to a new user without using asp login database ?

[image]

Comment: You have only shown us the HTML.  We need to see the vb or c# code that attempts to make a connection to the database.  But aside from that, the error pretty much says what you need to know.  The database does not exist or can not be found.

Comment: there is no C# code behind it ..., I want to use default Microsoft database for management of users...

Comment: Why do you think there is a default MS database?   Are you following some tutorial or something?

Comment: yes, I mean the database in 3rd picture I have uploaded... I have seen it in many tutorials... those tutorials say that if we use Microsoft Control Login Panel for the first time, asp makes this database...

Comment: Looks like it has created the MDF file based on your screen shot, you may need to configure your web.config to use the proper connection string for your MembershipProvider.

Comment: When you an using the out-of-the-box project within Visual Studio, it will create he .mdf database for you to handle logins.  If you them move that database away from it's default location, you will get that error as the project no longer knows where to find that database.

Comment: My problem is : Visual Studio does not make the .mdf Database